# Unable to parse the Test logs in windows machine using Nxlog

Tags: logging, nxlog

I wanted to process text logs and parse to json format using nxlog, but i dont find any document for configuring such custom logs in Nxlog- userguide, as i could see only event/system logs processing documents only available.

Can someone help me with the documents or help to configure the same?

Regards,
Dhamodharan

Answer (score 0):

There're docs for playing with JSON in NXLog. Depending on the version you're using, the functionalities set differs.

So, for NXLog Community Edition, take a look here: https://nxlog.co/docs/nxlog-ce/nxlog-reference-manual.html#xm_json

While NXLog Enterprise Edition can be found here: https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/xm_json.html

You will probably notice that the latter has some more capabilities :)